# Need an app to record continous gps with video

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications

Have you used an iOS app to record video along with keyed gps info?
Basically need a file to match video times with gps info
So not just the start gps point but every couple seconds whilst video is recorded.
For each journey two files would be created, a video file and a gps file.

Comment: [This newer question might get some answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459246/5472) if yours does not.

Answer (score 1):

IT'S FREE ONLY Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.
[Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vidometer/id552124663)