# How to record Audio & GPS on an iPhone

Tags: ios, audio, software-recommendation, gps, recording

How do I record a GPS track (including height) and audio simultaneously on an iPhone (iPhone 8 / iOS 11) in a way that I can later see which time of the audio relates to which GPS position?

Comment: Audio in addition might need a full custom app. [Have you checked out race track recording](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459246/5472) and used the microphone / bluetooth for narration if that's what you seek? https://racerender.com/TrackAddict/Features.html